# makefile for metapost: how to compile file-N.pdf

Tags: makefile, metapost

I want to let `makefile` manage the compilation of figures with `metapost`.
The source file is `file.mp`. This generates `.mps` files `file.1`, `file.2` etc. that are then converted to `file-1.pdf`, `file-2.pdf` etc.

Here are my rules:

```
export TEX = latex

%: %.1
        mptopdf $*

%.1: %.mp
        mpost $*
```

So that when I run `make file` it creates all the files.

However, I am not satisfied with this solution. Namely, I'd like to be able to let only one of the files be compiled (say `file-2.pdf`) by entering `make file-2`.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to write the rule for this, although I suspect it might be trivial.

I thought the problem could be solved by extracting the number from the file name given in the command line (i.e. extract `2` from `file-2`) but it is not clear to me how to do it either.

Comment: You are having trouble because you have cheated.  Your rules do not build files with the specified target names, and you do not actually model all the inputs or outputs.  It's not even clear to me how the rules presented build `file-2.pdf` at all if that is supposed to be achieved by running `mptopdf file.2`.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like your second rule does build a file with the specified target name when it succeeds, but the first rule still does not.  Do you have multiple `.mp` files that you want to process this way?  Do you not know in advance how many intermediate files will be produced from the `.mp` file?  You might be better off writing a shell script than a makefile.

Comment: This is exactly the case: I want the rules to be used for different `.mp` files with a variable number of figures. I'm trying to understand how can I let part of the filename be passed as an extension, or vice versa, if this is possible

Comment: Then like I said, you want a script, not a makefile.  `make` is not suited to build processes that need to be figured out as they proceed, and indeed, I don't think the makefile presented does all the work you say it does.  If you don't know in advance the list of files you're trying to build, at least in time to specify (all of) them on the command line, then `make` is not the tool you're looking for.